# How to enable Xbox One Developer Mode activation?

Tags: debugging, uwp, winjs, xbox

I following this link to enable developer mode on xbox.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/devkit-activation

Everything is fine except that after activating xbox with code, It is showing this message

[image]

If anybody can assist how to fix this? It's been two days and still showing this message. Thanks!

Comment: This bug has been 10 days long :-(

Comment: @Vincent you mean this is a known bug in app?

Comment: Yes, but you can try my answer below.

Comment: Hi, did the solution works?

Comment: @Vincent yes, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update

The newest app called 'Xbox Dev Mode', with Xbox Series S and X logo, which can work as before. But their docs haven't changed yet.
[image]

=========================================================

This may be a production bug of MS. But you can enable dev mode with some hidden skills.

```
Settings > System > Console Info > Press LB RB LT RT quickly > Developer Settings > Developer Mode.
```

Check it, your console will restart to dev mode.

Thanks.