# How can I solve this error during activation of XBOX Dev Mode?

Tags: uwp, xbox-one

I am seeing the following error during activation of developer mode on my XBOX One. I am following the same methods as in [How to enable Xbox One Developer Mode activation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825400/how-to-enable-xbox-one-developer-mode-activation).

[Error Message during DevMode Activation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbnCu.jpg)

I have tried the webpage in the error message, but to no avail. I have also tried the XBOX Dev Mode, but it crashes. Any suggestions on how to move forward and activate dev mode in the console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A number of Windows Developer accounts were disabled last year due to in-activity, but the Xbox Developer Mode accounts were not supposed to be disabled. You can contact Microsoft Store to get your account re-enabled via `reportapp@microsoft.com`